# What is wrong with my code trying to react to Popup Button

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am trying to make a popup appear when the user clicks a button with a warning, and if they click cancel, it will be dismissed, but if they click continue, I want it to present the view controller. Here is my code, but it only dismisses the popup no matter which button I press:

```
- (IBAction)latest:(id)sender {
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WARNING" message:@"Continuing will use internet and may cause app to slow down in large crowds" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
    [alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        UIViewController *NVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Latest"];
        [self presentViewController:NVC animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple - you need to pass `self` as the alert view's delegate, not `nil`.

Also, in your delegate method, don't hard code button indexes. Do this instead:

```
if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have 2 options to click. Indexes start at 0 not 1 so change `if (buttonIndex == 2)` to `if (buttonIndex == 1)`

Comment: I changed it to both 1 and 0 but neither worked

Comment: Hm ill play around a little and come back in 5 min

Comment: add NSLog(@"Called"); to se if the function is even getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I had to set the delegate to self, it was set to "nil".